# Two separate screens with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I got the two displays to work fine on NVIDIA binary (i'm guessing TwinView?), but when I set them to different screen (monitor0 to be on screen0 and monitor1 on screen1) it loads, I get the background but there is no panel so I can't start anything and the cursor looks like an X. My settings:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G70 [GeForce 7800 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fc000000-fcffffff ioport:bc00(size=128) memory:fe7e0000-fe7fffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia "Legacy" device.

If you installed a driver, try hopping down a kernel version.

Theres recovery boot option "failsafe X" or my method....

ctrl + alt + f2

login

> sudo su
>
> killall -HUP lightdm
>
> apt-get install fluxbox synaptic && xinit && DISPLAY=:0.1 xterm

and use the blackbox to install drivers.

Comment: yes i'm on legacy NVIDIA 304.117 so both monitors work fine when in one big screen (guess its TwinView??), both work fine if two separate screens with Xinerama, but i need to downgrade the kernel on 14.04 to have them as just two separate displays without Xinerama?

Comment: I had the same problem. It's a compiz issue